# What is the difference between the two Driver discs?

Tags: driver

I have a collection of old games given to me from a friend, and I happened to find two discs of the game Driver in it.

Why do two different disc arts exists for this game?
[image: The two discs]

Comment: The left one is the original game and the right one either copied or some kind of retro version (like Platinum games).

Comment: It seams like two copies of the same game ...

Comment: Looks like 2 different releases, it's still the same game tho.

Comment: There was also a [third disc art](http://199.101.98.242/media/images/52020-Driver_%28G%29-3.jpg) (the one i remember).

Comment: If you look closely, you can also see the second one has Atari logos. This would place it firmly as a re-release or later budget version of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a continuation of what @Riley said in the comments.  This is two separate releases of the same game as according to the [Driver Wiki Page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver_(video_game_series)) The game was originally published by GT Interactive and later published by Atari.  You can see the different company marks on the discs.  GT Interactive on the left and Atari on the right.  The left is circa 1999 and the right is anywhere from 2000-2006.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for! Thanks! (although I didn't see what you were referring to on the Wikipedia page).

Comment: Sorry Guy, I should have been more specific. [first paragraph] "Driver is a series of mission-based action-adventure... originally published by GT Interactive, later by Atari and now by Ubisoft." You can also see the Publish dates on the right side of the Wiki.

Comment: Ah ha, I see! Thanks! I also found as a reaffirming fact that on the two manuals I found for the games, one manual has the GT Interactive logo on it and the other has the Atari logo on it as well.